Problem in transaction session in mongoose
I'm running more than one database action. When one of these fails I want to revert the ran actions. Therefore I'm using a transaction session from Mongoose.
I am trying to determine whether the transaction is "sent" or "received". But i am getting all transactions marked as "received". I tried to check with the help of logs but only userId log is working, although balance get updated and transactions are completing.
I think there is some problem with logging system or asynchronous nature.
"/transaction"
router.post("/transfer", authMiddleware, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    // Log userId
    console.log("userId:", req.userId);

    const session = await mongoose.startSession();
    session.startTransaction();
    const { amount, to } = req.body;

    console.log("Amount to transfer:", amount);
    console.log("Recipient:", to);

    //fetch the accounts within the transaction
    const account = await Account.findOne({ userId: req.userId }).session(
      session
    );
    const toAccount = await Account.findOne({ userId: to }).session(session);

    console.log("Sender account found with userId:", account.userId);
    console.log("Receiver account found with userId:", toAccount.userId);

    if (!account || account.balance < amount) {
      await session.abortTransaction();
      return res.status(400).json({ message: "Insufficient balance" });
    }
    if (!toAccount) {
      await session.abortTransaction();
      return res.json({ message: "Receiver account not found" });
    }

    //perform the transfer
    await Account.updateOne(
      { userId: req.userId },
      { $inc: { balance: -amount } }
    ).session(session);
    await Account.updateOne(
      { userId: to },
      { $inc: { balance: amount } }
    ).session(session);

    //Determine the transaction type(sent/received)
    const transactionType = req.userId === account.userId ? "sent" : "received";

    console.log("transaction type:", transactionType);

    //save the transaction
    const transaction = new Transaction({
      senderId: req.userId,
      receiverId: to,
      amount: amount,
      type: transactionType,
    });
    await transaction.save({ session: session });

    //commit the transaction
    await session.commitTransaction();
    res.json({ message: "Transfer successful" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error transferring funds:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
});

authMiddleware
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const { JWT_SECRET } = require("../config.js");

const authMiddleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!authHeader || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    // console.log("Unauthorized: No Bearer token found in headers");
    return res.status(403).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
  }

  const token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET);
    req.userId = decoded.userId;
    // console.log("User authenticated. User ID:", req.userId);
    next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error verifying token:", error.message);
    return res.status(403).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
  }
};

module.exports = authMiddleware;


only getting userId logs

getting "received" in all transaction types

